# Reduce the intensity of an attitude

Tags: single-word-requests

Which verb can I use in place of the bolded text in the following sentence?

"He usually argues very aggressively but he has **reduced the intensity of his aggression** in the presence of guests."

Would "mellow down" sound appropriate here?

Comment: I think "curb" or "subside" would fit.

Comment: 'reined himself in somewhat'

Comment: Calmed down...?

Comment: I'd just used "mellows in the presence of company". The direction of mellowing is understood.

Comment: ..but he has a **conciliatory tone** in the presence of guests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He usually argues very aggressively, but he has ***restrained*** / ***tempered*** his aggression in the presence of guests.

> [**restrained**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=define+restrain&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ_SowAGoVChMIofn0puWWxgIVApMNCh3migXV&biw=1164&bih=600)
> *verb*: prevent oneself from displaying or giving way to (a strong urge or emotion). "Amos had to *restrain* his impatience";
> **synonyms**: control, keep under control, check, hold/keep in check, curb, suppress, repress, contain, dampen, subdue, smother, choke back, stifle;  see, Google
>
> [**tempered**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tempered) *adjective*: **3**. made less intense or violent, esp. by the influence of something else. see, The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Mollified, allay, pacified

> Make more temperate, acceptable, or suitable by adding something else; moderate